# Why isnt my JavaScript not styling my header

Tags: javascript, css, dom, styles

So i went as far as creating an entirely new HTML document to change my H1 class to a different color. Can someone please tell me why its not working? I dont understat because I literally copied exactly how to change the color and I've done it before but its not working now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script>
var box = document.getElementById("box");
boxStyle = box.style;

boxStyle.color = 'red';
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 id="box">NBA Legends</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try adding the script tag after the <h1> tag. The javascript is executed before the h1 gets the chance to be rendered.

Comment: Thanks that worked, however when i apply that to my script page attached to my html document it doesnt work @AndreiCACIO

Comment: please post another question with a code snippet and we will take a look. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you move the `<script>` tag after the `<h1>` tag it will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="box">NBA Legends</h1>
  <script>
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    boxStyle = box.style;

    boxStyle.color = 'red';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a best practice to put the `<script>` tag at the end of the document. This way the HTML renders and then the JS executes.

Comment: You need to execute this code after the page is loaded, maybe ate the onload event of the body. If you use jQuery you could do `$(document).ready(function () { your-code-here });`
Just one more tip: use classes insead, this way when you need to modify the styling you don't need to rewrite JS.

Answer (score 0):

here its working. JS is executing before html can be render.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<h1 id="box1">NBA Legends</h1>

</body>
<script>
var box = document.getElementById("box1");
boxStyle = box.style;

boxStyle.color = 'red';
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i did when i used the put the JavaScript on a separate page:
(And i made sure the source page name is yellow.js)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<script src="yellow.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1 id="box" onload="change()">NBA Legends</h1>

</body>

</html>

    function change() {
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    boxStyle = box.style;

    boxStyle.color = 'red';
    }
```